# Order of bindings in a tkinter treeview on single mouse click 'Button-1'

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, treeview

I am using a tkinter treeview. When I left-click on a line it gets highlighted and the function trview.focus() is giving me the current line. This is normal standard behavior.

But I would like to add another binding on the event 'Button-1'.

I am using the 'add = '+'' statement:

trview.bind('Button-1', function_call(), add = '+')

It is is working. My function is called as expected.

But I am always 1 click behind.
Means when I am using a

trview.focus() in my customized binding function it gives me the previous line, and not the one currently clicked.

It seems that my binding is called before the standard binding of treeview.

Is there any chance to force treeview to execute it's function first, so I am getting the current line in my own one, and not the old line?

I hope I phrased my question understandable.

I tried to set my binding on right mouse-click 'Button-3'.
Assuming there is a clash to have a standard bind mixed with a customized one (on the same event).
But it gave me the same result.

I think it is a general process flow that the treeview widget is executing all bindings first, before switching internally to the new line.

I also tried to do a trview.update() first. But also that don't worked.

Comment: Is there a reason you're getting the widget with focus rather than the selected item? You can bind to `<<TreeviewSelect>>` to have a callback run after the selection changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible events when you press a button: Press and Release. You hooked the Press event.
But the internal logic handling focus is evaluated when you release the button.
So, when you call focus, you receive the location of the last Release.
Be sure to ButtonRelease instead of ButtonPress.

```
trview.bind('ButtonRelease-1', function_call(), add = '+')
'''
```

Comment: My god. That easy. Many thanks for that explanation. It works perfectly.

Comment: @Nitram Your god should not be associated to a problem.

Comment: Your explanation isn't quite right, but the solution will still work. The focus is set on the button press, not button release. It's just that the default bindings don't fire until after the custom bindings on the widget.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the info. I never saw an authoritative document about tkinter internals but I thought that focus acted on Release in case someone clicked on one location and dragged to another before releasing.